# How to download pictures with selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

The goal is to download the profile picture of a given username if found

testsite : facebook

Using inspect element I copied the html part of the profile picture and got this [testcase](https://CadetblueUpbeatMicroscope.secteam.repl.co)

a white sqaure

```
def check_facebook(person_name):
    browser.get(f'https://facebook.com/{person_name}')
    print (browser.current_url)
    print (f"Profile Name : {browser.title.replace('| Facebook' , '' )}")
    time.sleep(5)
    elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    for elem in elems:
        URL_ = elem.get_attribute("href")
        reg = r"photo"
        if bool(re.search(reg , URL_))== True:
            puts(colored.green(URL_))
```

Using `browser.find_elements_by_xpath` returns an empty list

This function outputs link found in the profile page and some of them are photos of that person
Is facebook preventing such things

Comment: don't really understand your code, but seems like you'd want the SRC attribute.  You could then make a standard http request for that file.  Not sure if facebook prevents that request or not.  You could also use the driver to take a screenshot.

Comment: I tired using requests but all i got is bad timestamp error , so i turned to ouautogui to create the screen shot